# Gradle multi Project - apply plugin: spring-boot issue

Tags: gradle, spring-boot, multi-module

I started working on `Gradle multi project` and I have the project structure like

```
Parent
  build.gradle
  Project A
     build.gradle
  Project B
     build.gradle
```

I am trying to use spring-boot for that I have added `apply plugin: 'spring-boot'` in Parent Gradle but i am getting `Plugin with id 'spring-boot' not found.` I placed the apply plugin in `Project A` and deleted in Parent but still the same issue. If I separate the `Project A` from `Parent` project and run as new individual project it's working fine but not working in case of multi project.

If I delete `apply plugin: 'spring-boot'` from total project it gives `Could not find method compile() for arguments [org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web] on root project 'Project A'.` Appreciate your help on this. Thanks.

## EDITED

Added my Gradle files here

#### Parent Project

```
group 'com.mydomain'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'   

buildscript {
repositories{
    mavenCentral()
    
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.2.6.RELEASE'
}
}

subprojects {

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'spring-boot'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.11'
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
}
}
```

Project A

```
group 'com.mydomain'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'
// I added dependencies and apply plug-in here but got same issue
```

Project B

```
group 'com.mydomain'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'
```

### Parent Settings.gradle

```
rootProject.name = 'Parent'
include 'Project A'
include 'Project B'
```

Comment: The configuration you provided is working fine.

Comment: I am getting Task 'bootRun' not found in root project 'Project A'. error when I run boot run for Project A. Is there any good document on Gradle Multi Project? If I add the build script in Project A getting issue

Comment: Please have a look at this demo: https://github.com/Opalo/stackoverflow/tree/master/37708571. It works correctly.

Comment: yes, I am having the same thing but when I run bootrun from a then I am geeting issue. In multiproject can't we able to run specific subproject?